# Filter HTML table by color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a PHP script that is rendering an HTML table. I'm using Javascript to filter and sort the table from there using [this](http://tablefilter.free.fr).

The issue I have is that I need to filter by color of the cell. If the `bgcolor` attribute is not `#FF0000`, I want to hide the row.

How can I do this?

Comment: can you show us your code ?

Comment: FYI: [`bgcolor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.bgColor) attribute has been deprecated for a long time ago.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you set `bgcolor` as your attribute you could do:

```
$('table tr[bgcolor!="#FF0000"]').hide();
```

Or, as Teemu said, bgcolor is deprecated and you set it via CSS you could do:

```
$('table tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('backgroundColor') != 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';
}).hide();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhRP5/)

Comment: Why bother with jQ? Especially when it isn't tagged?

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to construct a [jQuery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) for selecting those elements. Another approach is to use a specific class (w/ the color) for each  and then filter rows by class.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this, using jQuery :

```
$('table td').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('bgcolor') != '#FF0000'){
      $(this).hide(); // or .css('display', 'none'); or whatever to hide it.
   }
});
```