# Sort table based on cell background color by clicking table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table where cell can be with:

1. No background color
2. rgb(255, 0, 0)
3. rgb(255, 165, 0)
4. rgb(0, 128, 0)

Here is a small piece of the table I am talking about:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<table class="w3-table-all">

<tr><th class="w3-center" style="width: 16.7%;">Name</th><th class="w3-center" style="width: 16.7%;">Run-1</th><th class="w3-center" style="width: 16.7%;">Run-2</th><th class="w3-center" style="width: 16.7%;">Run-3</th><th class="w3-center" style="width: 16.7%;">Run-4</th><th class="w3-center" style="width: 16.7%;">Run-5</th></tr>

<tr><th>test1</th><td>9130.47</td><td>392478.721</td><td class="w3-center">-</td><td>44301.148</td><td>44301.148</td></tr>

<tr><th>test2</th><td>747505.0087</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">368460.1843</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">64204.7407</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">106400.8238</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">106400.8238</td></tr>

<tr><th>test3</th><td>65.01%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 0, 0);">68.25%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 0, 0);">69.17%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 0, 0);">65.07%</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">65.07%</td></tr>

<tr><th>test4</th><td>67.53%</td><td>82.72%</td><td>69.67%</td><td>74.29%</td><td>74.29%</td></tr>

<tr><th>test5</th><td>-1906.877</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">-103.597</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">-87.119</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">-132.043</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">-132.043</td></tr>

<tr><th>test6</th><td>64.86%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 0, 0);">68.09%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 0, 0);">72.67%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 165, 0);">65.56%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 165, 0);">65.56%</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to sort the table by clicking any of the headers, and it will sort it based on the cells' color in that particular column. For example, when you click "Run-4", I want to sort the table in the following manner:

1. Red cells first
2. Orange
3. Green
4. No color

When I click "Run-4" again, it does the reverse:

1. No color first
2. Green
3. Orange
4. Red

I tried referencing several SO questions but had no success in implementing them:

- [Sort table rows based on background-color using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305641/sort-table-rows-based-on-background-color-using-jquery?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Filter HTML table by color [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887475/filter-html-table-by-color)
- [HTML table sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683712/html-table-sort) - plugins suggested here do not seem to do what I need.

Comment: I got the idea, but I didn't understand the order you want to sort, what should happen when clicked in run-2, for example? And why that sort order in run-4?

Comment: When you click Run-2, same ordering should happen. I just provided Run-4 as an example because it contains `<td>` with all 3 colors and no color as well

Comment: so, independant of the "run" clicked, it should sort the entire table from no color to red color and vice-versa, is it? Do you have some JS you already tried to post in your question?

Comment: Also, does this table is dynamic created? It comes in some format, as json, object or array? or it is static, created directly in HTML?

Comment: You can create a object with sort order key and color value and sort on them.

Comment: @CalvinNunes the table is dynamically generated with PHP. I did not write any custom JS because I tried to use examples that are out there (I also referenced them in question). I guess these things are mostly done with jQuery, but I do not really have any experience with it.

Comment: @CalvinNunes on sorting: yes, I want the sorting to be be based on colors as described. But most of the rows contain `<td>` with different colors so I want to sort based on cells in particular column. Let me know if I am clear

Comment: @SonamChhoegyal Do you have any examples? I would really appreciate that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Manipulating a table already in the DOM

Normally you would have all your table entries in an data structure and draw the table based on the structure. Sorting the table would be much easier because you would only need to sort the structure and update the table from that.

With that being said, here's how you might extract information from a table that's already present in the DOM and sort it.

You would first need to get the relevant row header cells and add a click event listener.

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0],
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
    headers = rows.item(0).getElementsByTagName("th"),
    i, sortOrder = 0;
// start from header 1 not 0 to avoid adding a click
// on the Name header
for ( i=1; i<headers.length; i++ ) {
    headers.item( i ).addEventListener( "click", function() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Within that function you need to do a few things:

1. Get the index of the current column, and then iterate over every cell in that column.
2. Go through the cells checking for red backgrounds. If a cell has a red background then clone its row to a sorted array.
3. Go through the cells checking for green, and if it has a green background, clone its row to the sorted array.
4. Go through checking for orange, and if so yada yada yada.
5. Go through checking for no background. In my code I checked for the absense of the style parameter, which works in this specific scenario. However if any cells have no background but do have some inline styling then they will not get sorted.
6. Replace the table's rows with the sorted rows.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0],
        rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
        headers = rows.item(0).getElementsByTagName("th"),
        i, sortOrder = 0;
    // start from header 1 not 0 to avoid adding a click
    // on the Name header
    for ( i=1; i<headers.length; i++ ) {
        headers.item( i ).addEventListener( "click", function() {
            // Get the index of the header within its row.
            // This is the same as the column number we'll
            // be editing
            var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call( this.parentNode.children, this ),
                sortKey = [ "rgb(255,0,0)", "rgb(255,165,0)", "rgb(0,128,0)", "" ],
                sorted = [],
                s, j;
            // initialise static variable for each click function
            // and increment with each click. If it is even
            // then sort normally, if odd then reverse the sort
            if ( !this.sortOrder ) this.sortOrder = 0;
            if ( this.sortOrder % 2 ) sortKey = sortKey.reverse();
            this.sortOrder++;
            // For each background colour...
            for ( s = 0; s < sortKey.length; s++ ) {
                // in each cell in the column...
                for ( j = 1; j < rows.length; j++ ) {
                    var cell = rows.item(j).children[ index ];
                    if ( sortKey[s] == "" ) {
                        // If we're on the last sort key..
                        // and there's no style (so considered
                        // a match) then deep clone into the
                        // sorted array
                        if (cell.outerHTML.indexOf("style") == -1) {
                            sorted.push(rows.item(j).cloneNode(true));
                        }
                    } else if ( cell.outerHTML.replace(/ /g,'').indexOf(sortKey[s]) != -1) {
                        // If background matches...
                        // clone the node into the sorted array.
                        // Use deep cloning to copy content
                        sorted.push(rows.item(j).cloneNode(true));
                    }
                }
            }
            for ( j = 1; j < rows.length; j++ ) {
                rows.item(j).parentNode.replaceChild( sorted[j-1], rows.item(j) );
            }
            
        }, false );
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<table class="w3-table-all">

<tr><th class="w3-center" style="width: 16.7%;">Name</th><th class="w3-center" style="width: 16.7%;">Run-1</th><th class="w3-center" style="width: 16.7%;">Run-2</th><th class="w3-center" style="width: 16.7%;">Run-3</th><th class="w3-center" style="width: 16.7%;">Run-4</th><th class="w3-center" style="width: 16.7%;">Run-5</th></tr>

<tr><th>test1</th><td>9130.47</td><td>392478.721</td><td class="w3-center">-</td><td>44301.148</td><td>44301.148</td></tr>

<tr><th>test2</th><td>747505.0087</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">368460.1843</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">64204.7407</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">106400.8238</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">106400.8238</td></tr>

<tr><th>test3</th><td>65.01%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 0, 0);">68.25%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 0, 0);">69.17%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 0, 0);">65.07%</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">65.07%</td></tr>

<tr><th>test4</th><td>67.53%</td><td>82.72%</td><td>69.67%</td><td>74.29%</td><td>74.29%</td></tr>

<tr><th>test5</th><td>-1906.877</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">-103.597</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">-87.119</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">-132.043</td><td style="background: rgb(0, 128, 0);">-132.043</td></tr>

<tr><th>test6</th><td>64.86%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 0, 0);">68.09%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 0, 0);">72.67%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 165, 0);">65.56%</td><td style="background: rgb(255, 165, 0);">65.56%</td></tr>
</table>
```

Reverse sorting is also implemented. A variable is attached to each click function, and incremented with each click. If it is even then the search is performed normally, if odd then the search is done in reverse. This method can lead to some unexpected behaviours when clicking sorting different columns multiple times.

## Building a table from an abstract structure

Currently your table is already present in the DOM. You are modifying its DOM structure to sort by colour; that is, you want to shuffle around `tr`s that already exist. A much more efficient way of doing this would be to have your table existing in an abstract sort of data structure from which the table would be drawn. Any sorting that needs to be done would be done to the data structure, and the table in the DOM would simply be updated from that structure.

A simple example of a data structure that contains background colours and values of your cells might be represented in a 2D array:

```
[ [ {bg: "", value: "9130.47"},     {bg: "", value: "392478.721"},                {bg: "", value: "-"},                        {bg: "", value: "44301.148"}, ... ],
  [ {bg: "", value: "747505.0087"}, {bg: "rgb(0, 128, 0)", value: "368460.1843"}, {bg: "rgb(0, 128, 0)", value: "64204.7407"}, {bg: "rgb(0, 128, 0)", value: "106400.8238"}, ... ],
  ...
]
```

Populating a table would then be a simple matter of two nested `for` loops to add the cells in their appropriate positions. You would have this code in a separate function so that it could be called whenever you change the order of your data structure.

This solution would generally be more robust, more efficient, have better maintainability and would allow new entries to be programatically added to the table, than sorting by modifying the current DOM structure.

Comment: Wow, this looks like it may be something that I need. However, what I noticed right away is that it sorts them horizontally, i.e. by clicking either 'test1', 'test2' etc. However, I wanted to click 'Run-1', 'Run-2' etc. I mentioned it in my question. Could you please update your answer so it can do that?

Comment: @tera_789 Updated the answer to sort columns not rows. I also added a check to reverse the column order if there was no change after sorting.

Comment: Perfect. I think we are getting close. I will be working on it tomorrow as well and will surely let you know how it went. For now, I can see that the sorting is working quite well, **however, the data is displayed wrong. i.e., Column "Name" is not changing. For example, data for "test-6" is displayed for "test-2" after sorting.**

Comment: Also, what do you mean by _would be much easier to do if the table already existed in some data structure_? What kind of structure?

Comment: @tera_789 updated code, I think it should be working as you need. Also added a section about using a data structure

Comment: On data structure: Oh I see. You are right. I am getting these data from a .csv file, which I parse with PHP and then display it. After it is displayed, users can choose whether to color or not the data by clicking a button. Coloring is done in the DOM with JS. So it is kind of hard to structure the data in a way you described. I will try your code some time later. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I accepted an answer. Thank you so much. I just wanted to ask why do you use `this` with `sortOrder`: `this.sortOrder`?

Comment: @tera_789 if I used `var sortOrder`, it would be removed by the garbage collector after every click so it would always be 0. By setting it as a property of the function the value of `sortOrder` persists between clicks.

Comment: What if you used `let`?

Comment: @tera_789 Whether you use `let` or `var`, the object you create has an _automatic_ lifespan and scope, bound to their containing function. That is, it will only remain alive within that function and will be removed by the garbage collector upon the function's return. Variables whose life persists after function completion are called _static variables_. JavaScript doesn't really have true static variables, but you can emulate them with object properties, as used above, or with function closures. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48923021/javascript-local-static-variable details a few options.